# SQL - Insert new row into an existing table based on another table entry

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a company table and a licence table. I need to insert a new row in the license table for every company in the company table that isn't already in the license table.

`License (ID,CompanyID,LicenseStart,LicenseEnd,CreatedDate,AddUser,UpdateUser,UpdateDate,TemplateId)`
The ID in this table is incremented by 1 when a new row is added.

`Company (ID,Name,CreateDate,CState,LocationID,LegalName)`

The default value that would be entered for each CompanyID that isn't already in the license table should look something like this.

`Insert (ID, @theCompanyID, GetDate(), DATEADD(day,14,GETDATE()), null,null,null,null null)`

`@theCompanyID` would be the CompanyID that isn't in the license table

I am very new to this so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @Politank-Z SQL Server 2012 sorry

Comment: Is the ID in the insert statement automatically generated? How is your two tables designed?

Comment: The ID in the license table is incremented by 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`license.id` is an identity column, so you do not need to insert it.

```
insert into license (CompanyID, LicenseStart, LicenseEnd)
    select c.id, GetDate(), DATEADD(day, 14, GETDATE())
    from company c
    where not exists (select 1
                      from license l
                      where c.ID = l.CompanyID
                     );
```

You also don't need to insert explicit `NULL` values for columns where you are not supplying values.  The default is to set these values to `NULL`.

If your start and end dates do not have a *time* component -- just the date -- then use this instead:

```
    select c.id, cast(GetDate() as date), cast(DATEADD(day, 14, GETDATE()) as date)
    from company c
    where not exists (select 1
                      from license l
                      where c.ID = l.CompanyID
                     );
```

Answer (score 1):

Do an `INSERT` with `SELECT`, use `NOT EXISTS` to make sure no existing company is inserted again. Something like:

```
insert into license (ID,CompanyID,LicenseStart,LicenseEnd,CreatedDate,AddUser,UpdateUser,UpdateDate,TemplateId)
select ID, theCompanyID, GetDate(), DATEADD(day,14,GETDATE()), null,null,null,null null
from company
where not exists (select 1 from company
                  where company.CompanyID = license.CompanyID)
```

Comment: Yes, I know, Jazz has to do some work here... That's why I wrote "Something like"...

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO License (CompanyID, LicenseStart, LicenseEnd)
SELECT ID, GetDate(), DATEADD(day,14,GETDATE())
FROM Company
WHERE ID NOT IN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT CompanyID
    FROM License
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `LEFT JOIN`:

```
INSERT  INTO License
        ( CompanyID ,
          LicenseStart ,
          LicenseEnd ,
          CreatedDate ,
          AddUser ,
          UpdateUser ,
          UpdateDate ,
          TemplateId
        )
        SELECT  ID ,
                GETDATE() ,
                DATEADD(DAY, 14, GETDATE()) ,
                NULL ,
                NULL ,
                NULL ,
                NULL ,
                NULL
        FROM    Company c
                LEFT JOIN License l ON l.CompanyID = c.ID
        WHERE   l.ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to do is to use the `EXCEPT` operator which is faster than `subquery` or `join` owing to it being a set function.

```
Insert License

select a.CompanyID, GetDate(), DATEADD(day,14,GETDATE()), null,null,null,null null
from 
    (select id from company 
    except
    select CompanyID from License
    )a
```

Answer (score 1):

Since OP has said that the `ID` in the license table is incremented by 1 then you can write your query like this:

```
INSERT INTO License(CompanyID,LicenseStart,LicenseEnd)
SELECT c.ID, GetDate(), DATEADD(day,14,GETDATE()))
FROM Company c
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT l.CompanyID
    FROM License l
    WHERE l.CompanyID = c.ID
)
```

You do not have to specify the column in the `INSERT` statement if the column is automatically incremented. Also I chose to use `NOT EXISTS` instead of `NOT IN` in the `WHERE clause for the reason that Martin Smith specified in this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists).